# PhoneGap + Android + media queries

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, media-queries

I have been struggling with this for a week now. I have read tons of posts/webs/tips&tricks, but I just can't figure this out.

I need to set CSS rules for different screen sizes and orientations. But the recognition it's not working.

I have tryed with:
min-width, max-width, min-height, max-height, min-device-width, max-device-width, min-device-height, max-device-height, orientation: portrait, orientation: landscape, media="only screen and (max...", media="screen and (max...", media="(max.."), all kind of convinations, none of this works for all the resolutions and orientations.

This is and example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iscroll.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iscroll_600.css"  type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iscroll_600.css"  type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 600px) and (orientation: landscape)"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iscroll_1280.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (max-height: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iscroll_1280.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 800px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>
```

How can I address this problem?
Thanks

dhcmega

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it works this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style320.css" media="(min-width: 241px) and (max-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style480.css" media="(min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style540.css" media="(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 540px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style600.css" media="(min-width: 541px) and (max-width: 600px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1280.css" media="(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1536.css" media="(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1152px) and (orientation: portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style320.css" media="(min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style480.css" media="(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style540.css" media="(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 960px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style600.css" media="(min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1280.css" media="(min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1536.css" media="(min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape)"/>
```

It is like creating different sets of resolutions that does NOT overlap at all

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it using javascript to see what is being returned by the media query, to check the results?

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "only screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)" );  

if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is exactly 600x1024 and portrait
}
else {
    // window width is exactly 600x1024 and portrait
}
```

[Link for reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/).

Comment: Hi, I loved your test, I would be great to know what is happening, but it looks like Android does not support it: 05-07 16:45:15.179: E/Web Console(2412): TypeError: Result of expression 'window.matchMedia' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:36

Comment: I am using this viewport: <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: I think I have solved it. It looks like I should create sets of resolutions that does NOT overlap each other at all.

Comment: oh!  well that would lead me to think it would load 2 css files, but that sounds reasonable., Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, it works. Don`t like it though. I will paste the whole things as "auto answer" after the 8 hours required by stackoverflow.