# how to use images on different devices on different resolution?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, screen-resolution

I'm using phonegap for making iphone apps.
I'm not sure exactly how to properly use the images to support all different resolutions on different devices (iphone, ipad).
I've googled it and some points out that I should use different css file for different screen.
I really hope that there should be an easier way.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 media queries to detect the phone dimensions and use the correct styling.  An example is available in this question: [PhoneGap + Android + media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484822/phonegap-android-media-queries)

See also "[How to use CSS3 media queries to create a mobile version of your website](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)".

**Example (in your HTML)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="screen-small.css" />
```

Comment: I see. I'm also wondering why people use two different images for different resolutions? why not just use one high-res image and resize it for the smaller resolution?

Comment: In a responsive layout, you may need to adapt the size of content displaying to better fit the screen being used.  For instance, on a device with a width of 480px, it doesn't make sense to show a 720px wide image.  Particularly in the case of iOS, retina displays will want to use a higher density resolution image to take full advantage of the better iPhone screen.